# CFA in R with lavaan: different results for fit measures with command fitmeasures() than in summary

Tags: r, model, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I'm calculating a confirmatory factor analysis with the following model:

```
library(lavaan)
CFA <- "
    A =~ BK01_01_z+BK03_01_z+ BK03_03_z+ BK03_04_z+BK03_05_z+ BK03_07_z+ BK03_08_z+ BK05_01_z+BK05_02_z+ BK05_03_z+ BK05_04_z 
    
    B=~GK04_01_z + GK04_02_z+ GK04_03_z+GK04_04_z+GK04_05_z 
    
    C =~ GS09_01_z+GS09_02_z
    
    Z=~A+B+C
    "

    fit <- cfa(CFA, data = df_clean, estimator ="WLSMV",
                  ordered = c("GS09_01_z",
                              "GS09_02_z"))
```

As you can see, there are two ordinal (binary) variables that are supposed to load onto one factor. It may also be important that the data is non-normal.

When I'm looking at the results now, I'm getting different results for different commands.

With:

```
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

I'm getting RMSEA = 0.069; CFI = 0.663; TLI = 0.609

with:

```
fitmeasures(fit, c("cfi","rmsea","srmr","tli"))
```

these are the results:

cfi = 0.964; rmsea = 0.041;  srmr = 0.060;  tli = 0.958

---

---

I've tried to search for my problem, but I couldn't find out why? Maybe someone has encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting Standard results vs Robust results.

For instance, when using alternative estimators such as MLM instead of ML, you get both a Standard and a Robust result.

I have tried it myself and by using  *fitmeasures* I get the standard results, not the robust. Check if that is the case for you as well.

J.